# Undefined for the type Item.Properties in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I'm modding Minecraft (version 1.16.5), and got an error when learning about "ItemInit":

Here is the code:

```
package com.test.core.init;

import com.serious1004.test.test;

import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemGroup;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.RegistryObject;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.DeferredRegister;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;


public class ItemInit {

    public static final DeferredRegister<Item> ITEMS = DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.ITEMS,
             test.MOD_ID);
    
    public static final RegistryObject<Item> EXAMPLE_ITEM = ITEMS.register("example_item",
        () -> new Item(new Item.Properties().group(ItemGroup.MISC))); #Error in this line!
}
```

Eclipse told me

> "The method group(ItemGroup) is undefined for the type Item.Properties"

Answer (score 0):

you need to change "group(ITEMGroup.MISC)" to "tab(ItemGroup.TAB_MISC)"